# Disable beep sound triggered by Process.Start

Tags: c#

I'm using the following command:

```
Process.Start("http://www.google.com");
```

When my code runs it beeps as if I did:

```
 SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
```

How can I disable this sound?

Here Is the code I'm Using:

```
        if (count == 0)
        {
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Buscar Informações do CEP Online?", "CEP Não Encontrado", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                //do something
               //Process.Start("calc.exe"); //will alsol beep
               Process.Start("Http://www.google.com.br");
            }
            else if (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
            {
            }
```

Comment: Install a working browser on your computer, or alternatively, reference one directly when calling `Process.Start`.

Comment: Does the browser open, did you try prefixing the URL with 'http://'?

Comment: The Browser open the url is an other and it has the http://, the problem is how I know witch browser the user has?

Comment: `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start` method will start the default web browser of the user. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/305703

Comment: It should not create beep on Process.Start().  Have you debugged your code and checked if it beeps on this line?  There might be something else that create that sound.  Do you have more code before this line and after if yes, could you please show that code.

Comment: Very likely the browser is making the sound.

Comment: I've debbugged and the sound comes when I run Process.Start even if I run calc.exe It will beep. I'v added the code I'm using.